If I use pagerview parent scroll view was nit working in react native


<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}  >
            <NewHeader />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, borderTopStartRadius: 150, borderTopEndRadius: 150, marginTop: height < 820 ? -heightDimension(84) : -heightDimension(87), backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: 'center' }} >
                    <View style={styles.countBg}>
                        <Text style={{ color: "#FFA500", fontFamily: 'Urbanist-Bold', fontSize: dimension(3.5) }} >{step + 1}/{wellnessSelected ? wellnessCollectionRewardsList.length : lifeStyleRewardsList.length}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Urbanist-Bold', color: "#FFA500", fontSize: dimension(6.5) }} >Rewards</Text>
                    <View style={[styles.unselectBg, { paddingHorizontal: dimension(0), paddingVertical: dimension(0), justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: "row", marginTop: heightDimension(3) }]} >
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            setWelnessSelected(true);
                            setLifeStyleSelected(false);
                        }} style={[styles.unselectBg, { backgroundColor: wellnessSelected ? "#FFA500" : "#FEF3DE", borderTopRightRadius: 20, borderBottomRightRadius: 20, zIndex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }]} >
                            <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Inter-Bold", color: "black", fontSize: dimension(3) }} >Wellness collection</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                            setLifeStyleSelected(true);
                            setWelnessSelected(false);
                        }} style={[styles.unselectBg, { backgroundColor: lifeStyleSelected ? "#FFA500" : "#FEF3DE", borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderBottomLeftRadius: 20, justifyContent: "center" }]} >
                            <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Inter-Bold", color: "black", fontSize: dimension(3), alignSelf: "center" }}>Life Style</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: heightDimension(2), }} >
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }} >
                        <Image source={image.reward_bg_1} />
                        <Image source={image.reward_bg_2} />

                    </View>
                    <AnimatedPagerView
                        testID="pager-view"
                        ref={page}
                        style={{ flex: 1, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, }}
                        initialPage={0}
                        onPageSelected={(e) => {
                            setStep(e.nativeEvent.position)
                        }}
                        showPageIndicator={true}
                        layoutDirection="ltr"
                        orientation="horizontal"
                        transitionStyle="scroll" >
                        {rewardsList.map((rewards, index) =>

                            <View key={index} style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: heightDimension(3), }} >
                                <View style={styles.rewardCard} >
                                    <View style={{ margin: dimension(4) }}   >
                                        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedFlip }] }} >
                                            <Image style={{ width: dimension(58), height: dimension(47), borderRadius: dimension(5), transform: reedemSelected ? [{ rotateY: '180deg' }] : [] }} resizeMode='contain' source={{ uri: rewards.reward_image }} />
                                        </Animated.View>
                                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Urbanist-Bold', fontSize: dimension(5.5), color: "black", alignSelf: 'center', marginVertical: heightDimension(1) }}  >{rewards.reward_name}</Text>
                                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Inter-Regular", alignSelf: "center", color: "black", textAlign: "center", fontSize: dimension(3), marginTop: heightDimension(1) }} numberOfLines={3} >{rewards.reward_description}</Text>
                                        <View style={{ justifyContent: "space-between", flexDirection: "row", marginHorizontal: dimension(2), marginVertical: heightDimension(2) }} >
                                            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }} >
                                                <Image style={{ width: dimension(7), height: dimension(7), }} source={image.coins_icon} />
                                                <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Inter-Bold", alignSelf: "center", color: "black" }} > {rewards?.points}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                                navigation.navigate(user.BookStack,{ screen: user.talkToTherapistSelected , params : {parent:"RewardsScreen"}, })
                                                // navigation.navigate(user.BookStack, {
                                                //     screen: 'FindCoachFilterPage',
                                                

                                                //     // Reset the stack by setting the routes array to only contain the target screen
                                                //     // and setting the index to 0
                                                    // state: {
                                                    //     routes: [{ name: 'FindCoachFilterPage' }, ],
                                                    //     index: 0,
                                                    // },
                                                // });
                                                // navigation.navigate( "Book" ,{screen : "SessionHome"});
                                                startFlipAnimation()
                                            }} style={styles.reedemBtnStyle} >

                                                <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Urbanist-Bold", color: "white", margin: dimension(1.2), fontSize: dimension(3.5) }} >Reedem</Text>

                                            </TouchableOpacity>

                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>




                            </View>
                            // <Text style={{color:"black",fontSize: 20}}  >{rewards.category_name}</Text>
                            //<Text>{rewards}</Text>
                        )}


                    </AnimatedPagerView>

                </View>

            </View>

        </ScrollView>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    unselectBg: {
        backgroundColor: "#FEF3DE",
        paddingHorizontal: dimension(3),
        paddingVertical: dimension(2),
        borderRadius: 20,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        minWidth: dimension(35),
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    rewardCard: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: dimension(8),
        elevation: 10,
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        maxWidth: dimension(70),
        margin: 1
    },
    reedemBtnStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFA500",
        borderRadius: dimension(6),
        marginTop: heightDimension(1),
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        paddingHorizontal: dimension(2),
    },
    countBg: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#FFA500',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 4,
        borderRadius: 35,
        marginVertical: 5,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },



})



The nested scroll inside the parent scroll was working but I don't need that if I remove the nested scroll the parent scroll was not working , if I remove the flex of the pagerview and add height to it parent scroll works , but as the data was dynamic I can't mention the height , please give me a solution
